# TinyMCE doesn't affect on nodes

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I've installed TinyMCE editor but when I change font style or anything else, I don't see any change in the published node. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default filtered html does not include text color and background color (No class or style or javascript attr) so be sure you choose full html not filterd html

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure the content has full HTML input filter, it may be that even though the source includes the customised html inserted by TinyMCE upon save it is all being stripped out.

Comment: Input filters are used when showing nodes (or comments), not when saving them. TinyMCE has an option to filter out some HTML tags, but in that case the tags are immediately removed when they are entered.